# What is the limit of $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{x}$?

Tags: calculus

What is the limit of $\sqrt{x^2}/x$ as $x \to -∞$?
Our professor said that when you take out the square root of a negative number, it should have a negative sign such that $\sqrt{(-x)^2} = -x$ so that the limit will become $-1$ since
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{x} = \lim_{x\to-\infty} -\frac xx = -1 $$
Evaluating $\sqrt{x^2}$ will give $x$ and $-x$. Then why is it that when you take out the square root of negative number squared, the value must be changed to negative?
If we write it this way $\sqrt{(-x)^2} = (-x)^{2/2}$ so that it is negative. There would be no need to change it to a negative sign since we know already that the root we got is already a negative number. And if we change it to negative, $-(-x) = x$.

Why is it that changing the sign is needed? **Or is it because only the positive roots are taken into account?**

Comment: $\sqrt{\ }$ is defined to mean the _positive_ square root. (If you want to talk about both, you can write $\pm\sqrt{\ }$.) Now, what is $\sqrt{(-3)^2}$? Well, it equals $\sqrt9=3$. What about $\sqrt{(3)^2}$? It also equals $\sqrt9=3$. As it turns out, $\sqrt{x^2}=\lvert x\rvert$. Do you see why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sqrt {x}$ is taken as the positive square root. If we wanted the negative square root, we would have put a negative in front. This is why mathematicians define $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. So for your limit: $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{x}=\frac{|x|}{x}=\text{sgn} x$$Now clearly as we take the limit to $-\infty$, it is going to be negative so our final answer is $$\large\boxed{-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

For all $x<0$, $\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{(-x)^2}=-x$ since $\sqrt{y}\ge0$ for all real number $y$. Hence $\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}x=-1$ for all $x<0$. What happens then as $x\to-\infty$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $x\neq 0$, then $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{x}=\frac{ \|x\| }{x}$.